# How to use a bluetooth mouse on an Android Phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, bluetooth, mouse, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I have a RedMi Note 3 with CM13 installed. I bought a Phone bracket to watch videos on my bed. To interact with my Phone without the bother to lift my hand, I tried to use a bluetooth mouse.

My Phone can connect to the bluetooth mouse, but shows no pointer and no reaction.

I searched throw the Internet, but the results are all about how to use a phone as a virtual mouse to control a PC. I really don't know how to filter them out. Could you give me any guide on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have got a Redmi Note 3 (Snapdragon) just recently and also have CM13 on it, and my Bluetooth keyboard/mouse combo connects and functions just fine.

[image]

All I can say is that your mouse might be faulty - test it somewhere else.

Comment: My mouse uses bluetooth 4.0. And it's fine on my Windows PC. I think I have to try another bluetooth mouse of my fellows